# Android (Xamarin) calendar with highlighted days and click events

Tags: android, xamarin, calendar

I'm trying to code a calendar page that highlights certain days with events on them. The calendar also needs to be able to disable certain dates from being clicked, such that the user is unable to select those dates. The designs of the calendar page are as follows:

[image: Days with events]

[image: Blocked out days]

I've looked for tutorials but was unable to find any that fits the requirements of my app, without using a library. Is there really no way to achieve this without the use of a library? And if I do have to use a library, how should I go about integrating it in this Xamarin application?

Any help or advice to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The standard Android `CalendarView` does not support highlighting multiple dates and providing custom date markers, using a 3rd-party library is the way most people go. you could also subclass CalendarView and override the draw method, but you will need to implement a number of the draw routines.... There are plenty of OSS calendar libraries on GitHub... pick one that matches your requirements are close as possible and create a Xamarin binding library for it...

Comment: @SushiHangover I see. Do you have any recommendations on where I should start?

Comment: I'd be very grateful if anyone attempted this on their own and can share insights. I'd rather not use external libraries other than the support packages.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements can take time to implement, using a 3rd-party Library is what you might be looking for.

This library: [XamForms.Controls.Calendar](https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar) has some great controls as what I can see will suit your needs, over all it has a great documentation so give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the below link ?

- https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar

There other UI library controls which you might be interested in

- **Xuni** http://www.goxuni.com/672835-a-deep-look-at-the-new-xuni-calendar-control/
- **Syncfusion** https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfcalendar/getting-started
- **Telerik** http://www.telerik.com/xamarin-ui/calendar

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom calendar earlier which is very simple and show Month and Year view.You could give it a try.

You can check out the code from here:

https://github.com/bhavya27/BXCalendar

Blog: https://medium.com/@bhavyajoshi2793/custom-calendar-in-xamarin-for-android-ios-windows-578f1136daec